# Make the Qmdisubwindow non movable

Tags: c++, qt, mdi

I am using three forms inside the mdi area in Qt. How do I make sure that these forms cannot be dragged/moved around the mdi area? I want the forms to be in a fixed position. How do I accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure an MDI is the correct approach for that? How about a fixed QWidget?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Johannes. I'll look it up today and will let you know if it works out for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!

Using

`subWindow1->setMouseTracking((false));`

prevents the subwindows inside an mdiarea to be moved around by the user.

A fixed QWidget too can solve the problem. Thanks to Johannes.